# How to retrieve all the repositories of subversion

Tags: linux, svn

I have installed Subversion on a Linux machine and want to backup all the repositories. I am able to get help on the script which will dump the repository based on name, but I need to give names manually. I want to know how to get all the repositories by any command or some work around so that i can automate it as well.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use bash to write a script that will fetch paths to the repositories and pass it to `svnadmin hotcopy`.